# What is the default value of the Zero Flag in x86 assembly MASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, eflags

For example if I have the following piece of code:

```
L1:
        cmp WORD PTR[ebx],0
        jnz found
        add ebx,2
        loop L1
        jmp notFound
```

Is the zero flag undefined for its default value?

Comment: The only place you test the value of the zero flag is immediately after the `cmp`, and it's perfectly well-defined then: it is 1 if `word ptr [ebx]` was equal to 0, and otherwise it's 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "default", unless you mean initial power-on before running the first instruction of the BIOS.  Any other time, the value is whatever previous instructions put there, just like other registers.

If you mean the very first user-space instruction of a process, that would depend on the kernel.  Try it in a debugger and see what your version of your OS happens to do.  For example, Linux zeros integer/vector registers before entering user-space (to avoid leaking any kernel data), and clears all the condition-code flags in EFLAGS.

---

Think of registers (including condition FLAGS) like you would uninitialized local variables in C.  (Except asm doesn't have Undefined Behaviour; you *can* read whatever garbage previous code left in a register, there's just no guarantee what the value will be.)

**That's why this code uses `cmp` to set FLAGS including ZF before running `jnz`, so it doesn't matter what was there before.**

---

Instructions like [`mul`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mul) that leave some flags "undefined" will set it to some value according to some internal condition on any given CPU, the manual just doesn't guarantee anything across different CPUs.  e.g. on some CPUs, `mul` may always clear ZF.  On others, it might get set according to the low or high half, or whole thing, being zero.  (Or it might *usually* do that but sometimes not, depending on microarchitectural conditions.)  The lack of documented guarantees means that experimenting to see what actually happens is *not* a safe way to write portable code.

But whatever happens, ZF will be either 0 or 1 even after an instruction like `mul`, and won't for example change a couple instructions after mul is finished.

Comment: Makes sense. So that CMP sets the flag to whatever I went, then the JNZ compares to see if its set to 0, correct?

Comment: @tagog97383: yes, of course.  I wondered why you were asking, since this code doesn't depend on the incoming value of FLAGS.  It would be weird if it did.  (Although you can certainly have blocks of code that intentionally depend on FLAGS set by an earlier jump, e.g. `cmp`/`jae foo` then the code at `foo` sorts out equal vs. above based on ZF without redoing the compare.

Comment: There are instructions that leave some flags undefined (e.g., https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mul). It could make sense to add something about these instructions to the answer.

Comment: @AndreasAbel: Good idea, that's worth discussing.

Comment: What are the initial values\states of special registers and non-special ones? E.g. `cs` points to the reset vector but I didn't find a source for that, what are the chances you can help me find the documentation for that?

Comment: @Roi: On powerup?  I think only CS:IP is documented / guaranteed to have any state (unreal mode with a high CS base), with the GPRs and other segment registers undefined.  Control registers do have defaults; Intel's manual should document any guarantees that exist for its CPUs.  AMD should similarly document this stuff in their manuals, presumably mostly agreeing with Intel, although since mobo-specific firmware is the only thing to run in this state, that's not essential.